# Any possibility for live-videostreaming within a-frame?

Tags: live-streaming

I want to create a site with a 360 video thats streamed from my computers 360 cam (ricoh theta s) and uses the possibilites of a-frame. I did not have any luck with embedding youtube livestreaming within a-frame though. I would have a webserver and the stream would not be really public so maybe there is some solution that involves selfhosting? Does anybody have any experience with achieving sth like this? i cant find anything related so far and this plays a crucial role in my robotproject...

EDIT 1:

I might specify even more after some research:

it would be perfect if a-videosphere and a-video would support sth like hls or mpeg-dash - streams. since that would need some kind of player for chrome and android stuff i think the easiest route would be to support a motionjpg-support because they are very easy to create. flashstreams can be good too but i dont think there is a future for that.

is there anything like that in the planning by someone because i am quite sure that nothing like that exists yet... i took 2-3 days of researching and find nothing about that topic... just a getUserMedia for webcam example showed up but its not good for my purpose.

another approach i could live with would be a routine that just autoreloads pictures in a-sky (if possible without flickering). i tried to integrate javascripts that are supposed to do that within normal divs and so but nothing worked...

or did somewhere someone get a stream of any kind running in a-videosphere and if so how?

EDIT 2:
i got it working... somehow... not really but looks promising...

the stream is provided by "yawcam" which uploads a new picture every second to my ftp. if i now click on the red sphere the script starts via addEventListener 'click' and the content of a-sky gets updated... is there any way to make a loop out of that script so one doesnt have to click anymore and it just update itself every second?

```html
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>joeinterface</title>
    <meta name="description" content="360 Video — A-Frame">
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.3.2/aframe.min.js"></script>

</head>



<body>

<script>
  AFRAME.registerComponent('set-sky', {
    schema: {default:''},
    init() {
      const sky = document.querySelector('a-sky');
      this.el.addEventListener('click', () => {
        sky.setAttribute( 'src', this.data + "?" + Math.random());
      });
    }
  });

</script>

<a-scene>
  <a-camera position="0 0 0">
    <a-cursor color="#4CC3D9" fuse="true" timeout="10"></a-cursor>
  </a-camera>

  <a-sphere color="#F44336" radius="8" position="-8 2 -8" set-sky="image1.jpg"></a-sphere>

  

  <a-sky></a-sky>
</a-scene>

 </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

so here is the solution for the proposed "kind-of" solution...

the picture "out" is updated via "yawcam" on my server every second and updated in the a-sky tag - even without flickering... so no sound but at least kind of a live-video-feed in a-sky.

```html
<head>

   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>joeinterface</title>
   <meta name="description" content="360 Video � A-Frame">
   <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.3.2/aframe.min.js"></script>

</head>



<body>

<script>
 AFRAME.registerComponent('set-sky', {
   schema: {default:''},
   init: function() {
     this.timeout = setInterval(this.updateSky.bind(this), 100);
     this.sky = this.el;
     
   },
   remove: function() {
     clearInterval(this.timeout);
     this.el.removeObject3D(this.object3D);
   },
   updateSky: function() {
     this.sky.setAttribute( 'src', this.data + "?" + Math.random());
   }
 });

</script>

<a-scene>
 <a-camera position="0 0 0">
   <a-cursor color="#4CC3D9 " fuse="true" timeout="10"></a-cursor>
 </a-camera>

 <a-sphere color="#F44336 " radius="2" position="-8 2 -8"></a-sphere>

 

 <a-sky set-sky="out"></a-sky>
</a-scene>

</body>
```